# How to import vuejs component dependencies in a MPA?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

In a single page app, I can do this to include a component inside a component.

```
$ npm install sagalbot/vue-select


<template>
  <div id="myApp">
    <v-select :value.sync="selected" :options="options"></v-select>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import vSelect from "vue-select"
  export default {
    components: {vSelect},

    data() {
      return {
    selected: null,
    options: ['foo','bar','baz']
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

How can I do this in a MPA, where I have bunch of js files  or sometimes inline javascript in different pages?
I am not using any build system.

Comment: I must be missing something. You do it the same way. Can you give more details of what you are trying to do?

Comment: The above syntax won't work where es2015 is not supported.

Comment: So you are not using a build system right?  Just including vue.js  in the header?

Comment: Yes, I am not using build system.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using vue-cli, but if for some reason that is not possible, then I believe,though I have never tried it, you would basically need to add all your components and code into a single long js file, or include them in the right order in your html documents.

Certain component libraries can work this way, like vuetify.  You simply include the whole vuetify.js file after vue.js and then you can use all the components available.

I think it would be quite a lot of work to do anything of much size, but if it is something really small you could add components in the following manner, one after another.

```
var componentTemplate = 
     `
         // Template code..
    `; 

Vue.component('my-cool-component', {
    template: componentTemplate, 
    data: function() {
           return {
              //
           }
       }
});
```